# How to exclude 0% coverage results from the report?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I am using jest to test unit tests of typescript. I am having many files with 0% Coverage.  Is there any way to ignore the files that have 0% coverage?

Comment: What do you mean "ignore" them?  How can you determine the coverage if you ignore it (to determine that it is 0% - and therefore to have ignored it in the first place?)  Or do you just mean you want to exclude 0% coverage results from the report?

Comment: What you said in your last line is exactly what I wanted to ask ( do you just mean you want to exclude 0% coverage results from the report?)

Comment: Surely if you have 0% coverage on one or more files that's a serious issue that you should fix? Or maybe those files are ones you don't care about covering with tests, which can be legitimate - but surely you make the decision of what to ignore/exclude based on what the files do and their function in your codebase, not simply because they happen to have 0% coverage at a particular point in time?

Comment: I agree with @RobinZigmond, in that if you are passing your tests but have 0% coverage on some files, you may be able to just delete them.  It seems they're not being used.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be not possible.

There are filter options that you can pass to the so called ["reporters"](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options) *(See the [@types/istanbul-reports](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/istanbul-reports/index.d.ts#L20))*, even one that's called ["skipEmpty"](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/istanbul-reports/index.d.ts#L64), but that doesn't seem to skip "0% coverage". I don't understand yet what it should skip exactly.

E.g.:

```
const config = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: [
        ['text', { skipEmpty: true }],
    ],
    // ...
};
```

I suggest to exclude the files you don't want to see by using e.g.
[coveragePathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragepathignorepatterns-arraystring)

#### Details:

The report line with 0% coverage would have to be excluded inside the "reporter", e.g. in a similar way as done in the "text reporter" from the istanbuljs package, where it handles [the "skipEmpty" option](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/istanbul-reports/lib/text/index.js#L189) (I'm not sure what the "skipEmpty" and "skipFull" options do, but apparently not skipping 0% coverage).

E.g. you can try and add this code to the file `node_modules/istanbul-reports/lib/text/index.js` (if you are using the "text" reporter):

```
if( metrics.lines.covered === 0 ){
    return '';
}
```

Of course, that change would be automatically overwritten when the node_modules are updated.